# create a hash number from columns

Tags: asp.net, hash, datatable, aspxgridview

I am creating a data table in ASP.NET from an ASPxGridView:

I want to generate a hash value of the all the items in the column "ItemId" (these are integers) and place this hash value the column "PlanId" (in all rows). Any help appreciated.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxButton button1 = sender as ASPxButton;
    ASPxPageControl pageControl = (ASPxPageControl)button1.NamingContainer;
    ASPxGridView ASPxGridView2 = (ASPxGridView)pageControl.FindControl("ASPxGridView2");

    DataTable ItemsTag = new DataTable();
    ItemsTag.Columns.Add("PlanId", typeof(int)); ---The type might be different-----(binary?)
    ItemsTag.Columns.Add("ItemNumber", typeof(int));
    ItemsTag.Columns.Add("ItemId", typeof(int));
    ItemsTag.Columns.Add("ManufacturerId", typeof(int));
    ItemsTag.Columns.Add("RetailerId", typeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < ASPxGridView2.VisibleRowCount; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = ItemsTag.NewRow();
        row["PlanId"] = -----Hash Value enter here -----("Hash Value");
        row["ItemNumber"] = ASPxGridView2.GetRowValues(i, "ItemNumber");
        row["ItemId"] = ASPxGridView2.GetRowValues(i, "ItemId");
        row["ManufacturerId"] = ASPxGridView2.GetRowValues(i, "ManufacturerId");
        row["RetailerId"] = ASPxGridView2.GetRowValues(i, "RetailerId");
        ItemsTag.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Copy the data
    CopyData(ItemsTag);
}
```

Comment: So many hash libraries, pick one and use it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to, that's why I am here...

Comment: Ok, look for "hash c#", then make some tests from the hash libraries you find. You can also make this simple `ASPxGridView2.GetRowValues(i, "PlanId").ToString().GetHashCode()` but I do not know what you look for. The hash is something special, do you want unique ? do you want to be the same over asp.net versions ? do you want a fast, a large, what...

Comment: Yes, I want uniqueness. Every set of ItemIds should generate a different hash value. Also I am filling the entire column of PlanId with this one hash value, in a sense "tagging" this set of items. Smaller hash is better for me, even better if it is an int.

Comment: hash can not offer uniqueness. Try the guid